# How to connect python to IBM DB2?

Tags: python, db2

I need help with the following python code, I'm trying to connect it to IBM DB2 but I'm getting this error.
OperationalError:

> ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: Exception('[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N 
>   A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being
>   used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location
>   where the error was detected: "10.80.11.70".  Communication function
>   detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s):
>   "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-30081')

Below is my code.

````
import ibm_db_dbi as db

conn=db.connect("DATABASE=xxxx;HOSTNAME=xxxxxx;PORT:5950;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=user;PWD=password;","","")

for t in conn.tables():
    print(t) ```
````

Comment: Please use the equals character `=` instead of colon when specifying the port number. i.e `...;PORT=5950;...`   Also verify that you have the correct port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess 10.80.11.70 is the IP of your db2 server ?

several reasons to receive SQL30081N.  your case is a TCP/IP protocol error. not a db2 issue. 
You are getting 10061, which is Connection-Refused. 
Look at this article and make sure of what is described there. 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql30081n-tcpip-communication-errors

You may also check your firewall settings.